# Clonar clase y función con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero clonar la clase`tcal` en el input `FECHA` y la función `foco` del mismo input, la clase es para convertir el input en calendario y la función para que al perder el foco pase al siguiente input, todo esto funciona correctamente en el la tabla base, pero al clonar no copia la función, he intentado hacerlo de la forma en la que copio las otras funciones y no me funciona, dejo todo el código para saber que estoy haciendo mal.

**SCRIPT**

```
function limpiar_valor(input){ 
  if(input.tagName == 'INPUT'){ 
    //Dejamos el valor en ''. 
    input.value = ''; 
  } 
} 

function foco(CUENTA){ 
  document.getElementById(CUENTA).focus(); 
} 

$(function(){ 
  // Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base 
  $("#adicional").on('click', function(){ 

    //Tenemos que añadirle los eventos a los input de tipo text 
    var fila_clonada = $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila-fija'), 

    //Los hijos 6, 8 y 10 son los que contienen los inputs que deberan tener los eventos. 
    celdas = fila_clonada[0].getElementsByTagName('td'); 

    //Removemos los atributos a los inputs clonados. 
    limpiar_valor(celdas[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]); 
    limpiar_valor(celdas[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]); 
    limpiar_valor(celdas[8].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]); 
    limpiar_valor(celdas[10].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]); 

    //Añadimos la fila clonada 
    $("#tabla").append( fila_clonada ); 

  }); 

  // Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
  $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){ 
    var parent = $(this).parents().get(0); 
    $(parent).remove(); 
  }); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" /><script 
type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="" name="form">
<table class="table bg-info" id="tabla">
  <tr class="fila-fija">
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="FECHA[]" id="FECHA" class="tcal" onblur="foco('CUENTA');" /> 
    </td> 
    <td align="center"><input value="" type="text" name="CUENTA[]" id="CUENTA" />
    </td> 
    <td align="center"><input type="number" name="OT[]" id="OT" value=""/> 
    </td> 
    <td> 
        <select name="CIUDAD[]" id="CIUDAD" title="Ciudad"> 
            <option value="">Selecciones...</option> 
            <option value="CALI">CALI</option> 
            <option value="JAMUNDI">JAMUNDI</option> 
        </select> 
    </td> 
    <td> 
        <select name="TIPO_ACTIVIDAD[]" id="TIPO_ACTIVIDAD" onchange='cargarSUBTIPO(this);'> 
            <option value="">Selecciones...</option> 
            <option value="Cambios de equipos">Cambios de equipos</option> 
            <option value="Control Remoto">Control Remoto</option> 
        </select> 
    </td> 
    <td> 
        <select name="SUBTIPO[]" id="SUBTIPO" disabled="disabled" onchange="seleccionado_SUBTIPO(this.value);"> 
            <option value="">Selecciones...</option> 
        </select> 
    </td> 
    <td align="center"><input placeholder="Item" value="" type="text" name="ITEM_RE[]" id="ITEM_RE" onkeyup="cargar_precio(this.value.toUpperCase(), this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td')[10].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);"/> 
    </td> 
    <td> 
        <select name="OBSERVACIONES[]" id="OBSERVACIONES"> 
            <option value="">Selecciones...</option> 
            <option value="Mover Toma">Mover Toma</option> 
            <option value="Extender Toma">Extender Toma</option> 
         </select> 
    </td> 
    <td align="center"><input placeholder="Cantidad" value="" type="number" name="CANTIDAD[]" id="CANTIDAD" onkeyup="operacion(this, this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td')[10].getElementsByTagName('input')[0], this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td')[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);" title="cantidad" /> 
    </td> 
    <td align="center"><input value="" type="text" name="OT_RECUPERADA[]" id="OT_RECUPERADA"/> 
    </td> 
    <td align="center"><input placeholder="Valor" value="" type="text" name="VALOR_RE_MO[]" id="VALOR_RE_MO"/> 
    </td><input type="hidden" name="USUARIO[]" id="USUARIO" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?>"> 

    <td class="eliminar"> 
        <button>Eliminar src="../IMAGENES/eliminar3.png" style="width: 12px; height: 13px;"> 
        </button> 
    </td>  

    <div class="btn-der" align="center">
        <button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">+ Filas</button>
        <input type="submit" name="insertar" id="insertar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-info"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: la clase tcal funciona implícitamente sobre todos los elementos con `class="tcal"` y tú quieres que los elementos añadidos dinámicamente también tengan este comportamiento?

Comment: si, exactamente.

Comment: Entonces tendrías que ver en la documentación de `tcal.js` cómo inicializar manualmente un elemento, porque esa "magia" de instanciar un `tcal` en cada elemento con `className` tcal ocurre sólo cuando recién se renderea el DOM. No se aplica a los nodos insertados a posteriori

Comment: Que puedo hacer para darle solución a esto?

Comment: Revisa la documentación de `tcal.js` como te dije. Debe haber un método del tipo `$('#contenedor').tcal();`

Comment: Miento, no parece usar jQuery. Estás usando algo como esto? https://github.com/mangstadt/emc-investigator-node/blob/master/app/static/js/tcal/tcal.js

Comment: Otra pregunta. En los elementos clonados funciona el evento `onblur`? Aunque no tengan un calendario sí debiera ocurrir que al salir de éstos (por ejemplo usando esc, o tab) el foco pasara al elemento `#CUENTA`

Comment: si funciona el onblur pero solo en la primera fila, cuando lo hago en una fila clonada pasa pasa pero al elemento `CUENTA` pero de la primer fila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primero: comportamiento tipo calendario**

Considerando que `tcal.js` es o se parece a lo que hay en [este repositorio de github](https://github.com/mangstadt/emc-investigator-node/blob/master/app/static/js/tcal/tcal.js), vemos que esa librería fija un listener al evento `window.load` (cuando termina de cargar el DOM) que gatilla la función `f_tcalInit`:

```
function f_tcalInit () {

    if (!document.getElementsByTagName)
        return;

    var e_input, a_inputs = f_tcalGetInputs();
    for (var n = 0; n < a_inputs.length; n++) {
        e_input = a_inputs[n];
        e_input.onclick = f_tcalOnClick;
        f_tcalAddClass(e_input, A_TCALCONF.cssprefix + 'Input');
    }

    window.A_TCALTOKENS_IDX = {};
    for (n = 0; n < A_TCALTOKENS.length; n++)
        A_TCALTOKENS_IDX[A_TCALTOKENS[n]['t']] = A_TCALTOKENS[n];
}
```

Y lo que hace esa función es

1. Traerse todos los elementos `input` de tipo `text` que tengan la clase `tcal`
2. A cada uno, añadirle el comportamiento `onclick` de gatillar la función `f_tcalOnClick`
3. A cada uno añadirle una clase (que en este caso es `tcalInput`)

Respecto al último punto, si el elemento ya tiene esa clase, tiene la inteligencia de no añadirla por segunda vez. En cuando a sobreescribir la propiedad `onclick` también es inofensivo redeclararla una y otra vez.

En conclusión, cada vez que clones una fila, debes llamar tú mismo a `f_tcalInit()` y con eso las filas nuevas tendrán el comportamiento de calendario.

Esto lo harías poniendo:

```
$("#tabla").append( fila_clonada );
f_tcalInit();
```

Puedes llamar la función porque el script `tcal.js` ya la declaró en el ámbito global.

**Segundo: comportamiento onblur**

Respecto a `onblur`, la función que le estás pasando manda a fijar el foco en un elemento con id `#CUENTA`. Pero resulta que ese id ya está en la primera fila y los ID deben ser únicos en el documento. Si todas tus filas clonadas tienen un elemento con ese ID, siempre te mandará al primero. Mi sugerencia es que en cambio le asignes una clase 'CUENTA'.

En vez de

```
  <input value="" type="text" name="CUENTA[]" id="CUENTA" />
```

poner

```
  <input value="" type="text" name="CUENTA[]" class="CUENTA" />
```

Y en vez de poner en duro la propiedad `onblur`, declararla  mediante un listener que escuche a toda la tabla:

En vez de tener la función

```
function foco(CUENTA){ 
  document.getElementById(CUENTA).focus(); 
}
```

Y ponerla en duro como

```
<input type="text" value="" name="FECHA[]" id="FECHA" class="tcal" onblur="foco('CUENTA');" />
```

Sólo deja

```
<input type="text" value="" name="FECHA[]" id="FECHA" class="tcal" />
```

Y declara un listener usando jQuery (**afuera** del evento que clona las filas)

```
$(function(){ 

  $("#tabla").on('blur','.tcal', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.CUENTA').focus();
  });

  // Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base 
  $("#adicional").on('click', function(){ 
     ...
  });

});
```

Que significa: "pon un listener sobre la tabla en donde cada vez que ocurra un evento `blur` en un elemento con clase `tcal`, encuentra un elemento con clase `CUENTA` que esté en la misma fila (o sea el mismo elemento `tr`), y dale focus a ese elemento".

Y con eso creo que todo debiera funcionar.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, me sirvió para otras funciones que tenia, gracias por tu interés y tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Clonar objeto y función:

```js
Object.prototype.clone = function(){return this};
Function.prototype.clone = function(){return this};

function ES0(){
 this.version = "0.001";
}
function consoled(){console.log('Clicked');}

var clase = new ES0(),
    clonobj = clase.clone(),
    clonfunc = consoled.clone();

window.addEventListener("click", clonfunc); // Funcion clonada.
console.log(clonobj.version); // Objeto clonado.

var directa = clase;
console.log(`Copia directa: ${directa.version}`); // Copia directa.
```

Comment: Hmmm pero eso podría hacerse via asignación directa. `clonobj=clase` según entiendo. ¿No es así?

Comment: Claro, se puede hacer de muchísimas formas.

Comment: De hecho, la edite para que lo vea el que preguntó.

Comment: De acuerdo, probare de la forma en la que lo colocaste.

Comment: Pero esto en realidad no responde a la pregunta. Lo que quiere el OP no es saber la forma genérica de clonar objetos o funciones, sino cómo aplicar un comportamiento a un DOMElement clonado después del evento `load` del documento, considerando que usa una librería que mágicamente asigna comportamientos cuando el documento se renderea

Comment: Me guio según el título, además el OP, nisiquiera me ha respondido, quisás busca hacer element.clone() o algo así y luego poder editarlo, pero no ha aclarado nada..

Comment: Bueno pido disculpas, si no comprendo todo lo que hablan a la perfección pero llevo poco tiempo trabajando con JS y hay documentación y conceptos que no tengo muy claros, y que tengo que estudiar obvio, lo que quiero, en palabras castizas, es que cada que clone una fila, pueda utilizar el calendario de `tcal` y la función `foco` las cuales puse en el código de la pregunta, de antemano agradezco su ayuda e interés.

Comment: @AnderssonViveros confírmame de dónde sacaste el código de `tcal.js`

Comment: Es el código que amenadiel puso, de GitHub.

Comment: Creo entonces que la respuesta que te puse debiera funcionar